# Most concise way to create a python dictionary from local variables

Tags: python, dictionary

In Objective-C, you can use the `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` macro to create a dictionary like this

```
NSString *foo = @"bar"
NSString *flip = @"rar"
NSDictionary *d = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(foo, flip)
// d -> { 'foo' => 'bar', 'flip' => 'rar' }
```

Is there something similar in python? I often find myself writing code like this

```
d = {'foo': foo, 'flip': flip}
# or
d = dict(foo=foo, flip=flip)
```

Is there a shortcut to do something like this?

```
d = dict(foo, flip) # -> {'foo': 'bar', 'flip': 'rar'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars)

> **vars([object])**
>   Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.
>
> Objects such as modules and instances have an updateable `__dict__`
>   attribute; however, other objects may have write restrictions on their
>   `__dict__` attributes (for example, new-style classes use a dictproxy to prevent direct dictionary updates).

so

```
variables = vars()
dictionary_of_bindings = {x:variables[x] for x in ("foo", "flip")}
```

Comment: Just tested this, really enjoyed learning the dictionary comprehension technique, didn't realize that it available in python2.7. Although instead of vars(), globals() need to be used because the comprehension executes in a different variable scope. for instance,
 >>> a = { x: locals() for x in ('params', 'callbac')}
>>> a
{'callbac': {'.0': <tupleiterator object at 0x104df2bd0>, 'x': 'callbac'}, 'params': {'.0': <tupleiterator object at 0x104df2bd0>, 'x': 'callbac'}}

Comment: @Tony, argh - quite right about the local scope. You'll need to extract vars() before the dict comprehension. globals won't work in general since you would usually be interested in the local variables

Comment: I tested it with `globals()` and it seemed to work. The previous local variables seem to now populate the globals() dictionary if I understand correctly. I haven't tested corner cases though.

Answer (score 5):

No, this shortcut in python does not exist.

But perhaps this is what you need:

```
>>> def test():
...     x = 42
...     y = 43
...     return locals()
>>> test()
{'y': 43, 'x': 42}
```

Also, python provides `globals()` and `vars()` build-in functions for such things.
See the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals).

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't quite have a way to do this, though it does have the functions `locals` and `globals` which can give you access to the *entire* local or global namespace. But if you want to pick out selected variables, I consider it better to use `inspect`. Here's a function that should do that for you:

```
def compact(*names):
    caller = inspect.stack()[1][0] # caller of compact()
    vars = {}
    for n in names:
        if n in caller.f_locals:
            vars[n] = caller.f_locals[n]
        elif n in caller.f_globals:
            vars[n] = caller.f_globals[n]
    return vars
```

Make sure to check that it works in whatever Python environment you're using. Usage would be like so:

```
a = 1
b = 2
def func():
    c = 3
    d = 4
    compact('b', 'd')  # returns {'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

I don't think there's any way to get away without the quotes around the variable names, though.

Comment: `def compacter(name_str):  compact(name_str.split())`

`# compacter('b d') => {'b': 2, 'd': 4}`